# Show text when the cursor hovers over an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to accomplish of the task of displaying text below an image when you hover over it. I do not want to use the `title` attribute, because I want to be able style the text.

An example would be at [Dribbble](http://dribbble.com). When you hover over some of the pictures, the text **PRO** shows up next to the name of the person that posted the picture

Comment: I think, You want to add tooltip?

Comment: hmmm. no ... I am trying to create games covers and when you place the mouse on them ... the name of the game appears in the middle of the image

Comment: something like this : http://dribbble.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this quick [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/KumcX/).

Your HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="caption">this is my caption</div>
        <img src='http://dribbble.com/system/users/22122/screenshots/244072/empirestate02_d_teaser.png?1314126367'/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="caption">this is my caption</div>
        <img src='http://dribbble.com/system/users/22122/screenshots/244072/empirestate02_d_teaser.png?1314126367'/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="caption">this is my caption</div>
        <img src='http://dribbble.com/system/users/22122/screenshots/244072/empirestate02_d_teaser.png?1314126367'/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="caption"><span>this is my caption</span></div>
        <img src='http://dribbble.com/system/users/22122/screenshots/244072/empirestate02_d_teaser.png?1314126367'/>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Css

```
ul li{ float:left; padding:20px; border:solid gray 4px; margin:5px;}
ul li div{display:none; background:white; opacity:.5; position:absolute;}
```

and your javascript

```
$('ul li').mouseenter(function(){
    var image= $(this).find('img'),
        caption = $(this).find('div');

    caption.width(image.width());
    caption.height(image.height());
    caption.fadeIn();
}).mouseleave(function(){
     var image= $(this).find('img'),
        caption = $(this).find('div');

    caption.width(image.width());
    caption.height(image.height());
    caption.fadeOut();
});
```

This should give you an idea of how to achieve what your looking for. It obviously could be improved. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

give your text inside a div and then show that div on hover of image like this..

```
<div id="div">Hiiii</div>
$('#img').live('mouseover', function(){
$('#div').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a function with the argument as the text you want to display on hovering the image. Then in that function you dynamically create a div and place the text within that div and also dynamically position the div according to the  mouse pointer position and you can also add css for the div give ur styling effects. Call this function on the mouseover of the image.
Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use jquery tooltip for that. Below are the links from where you can find the best tooltip plugins.

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/

http://slodive.com/web-development/best-jquery-tooltip-plugins/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {

    $('.bar').css({opacity:0});

    $('.foo').hover(function() {
        $('.bar').stop().animate({
            opacity: 1
        },'fast');
    },function() {
        $('.bar').stop().animate({
            opacity: 0
        },'fast');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this http://jsfiddle.net/konglie/SXFEn/