# Javascript mouseenter() hover function not working

Tags: javascript, hover, mouseover, mouseenter, mouseleave

I've been trying to create an effect where I hover over an image and the entire image goes white with text but my code isn't working, would anyone mind talking a look at letting me know what i've been doing wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/MBsbj/

```
<div class="frontImages"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-24" alt="biryani sideimage" src="http://tandoorifreshonline.com.mlseo.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/biryani-sideimage.png"/>
<div class="hoverText">HOVER TEXT HERE</div>
</div>

    $('.frontImages').mouseenter(function(){
$('.hoverText').fadeIn();
});

.hoverText {
display:none; 
}
```

Note - this code was based off of this thread: [Show text when the cursor hovers over an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170759/show-text-when-the-cursor-hovers-over-an-image) - however when I entered the code from the answer, it doesn't seem to work either. http://jsfiddle.net/nMCbY/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code works as it is you should only add an reference to `jQuery` in your `JSFiddle` to make it work. See your updated fiddles: http://jsfiddle.net/MBsbj/1/ and http://jsfiddle.net/nMCbY/1/

I've also edited the second fiddle to position the caption over the image, instead of under by adding:

```
caption.offset({ top: image.position().top })
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/nMCbY/3/

Comment: Thanks! It think I have everything correct on the website that I'm working on but it looks like it still isn't working for me... would you mind taking a look and seeing if I did something wrong?

http://tandoorifreshonline.com.mlseo.net/

Currently all the images on the front page are using the same class so hovering over any of them should reveal all of their hover text - I'll fix it later but I wanted to make sure it worked first.

Comment: I took a look and this works: jQuery('.frontImages').mouseenter(function(){ jQuery('.hoverText').fadeIn(); }); To bind jQuery to $ see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6109983/849741

Comment: Thanks for looking over it. This is so odd to me. I used your code but it only works if I load the page, go into firebug and add or remove something insignificant like an extra space or something from the code. Any reason it'd be doing that? Thanks so much for helping btw.

Comment: You should initialize the code in a document ready (where you showed the jQuery loaded alert before.) Like this:  jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
   jQuery('.frontImages').mouseenter(function(){ jQuery('.hoverText').fadeIn(); });
});