# Display image when the cursor hovers over text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to **display an image** when the cursor hovers over **text**, based on my search, I have only been able to find the **example of Dribble** :
 ["shows text when the cursor hovers over an image"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170759/show-text-when-the-cursor-hovers-over-an-image).
Is there any way to find the reverse way that **shows image** when the cursor hovers over **text**?

For instance, I want to show an image when the is cursor over the text below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If image and text are in same container then you can do it with only css:

```
.container img {
opacity: 0;
}
.container:hover img {
 opacity: 1;
}
```

If they are in different containers then jQuery will help you:

```
$('.text').hover(function(){
 $('.image').css('opacity', '1');
 }, function(){
   $('.image').css('opacity', '0');
 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4k9okj14/

Comment: this is great answer

Answer (score 2):

if you want to put image from css then you can do like this.

```
<div class="image-hover"><p>Hover the text</p></div>
```

and css is,

```
.image-hover p:hover{
   background-image: url(../img/one.jpg);
   width: 400px;
   height: 400px;
}

.image-hover p{
   display: block;
}
```

and if you want to put image from HTML then you can do like this.

```
<div class="image_hover"><a>Hover the text<img src="img/one.jpg"></a></div>
```

and css is:

```
.image_hover p img{
  display: none;
}

.image_hover p:hover img{
   display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

make the text in anchor tag

```
<a href="#">Your Text</a>
```

css:

```
a:hover{
  /* write your img path or logic etc here */
}
```

Comment: @Rayon his answer is partially correct, look at the answer below.

Comment: @AniMenon, May be.. I have never heard of `hove` pseudo-selector

Comment: @Rayon He meant hover.

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS:

```css
a>div { display: none; }
a:hover>div { display: block; }
```

```html
<a>Caption 1
<div><img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg" /></div>
</a>
<br />
<a>Caption 2
<div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTqgYUgfs11x4RdvBusUV5MOVW6ArdCgCWIzaBwRaEZA2IxP6LqxyNNQA" /></div>
</a>
<br />
<a>Caption 3
<div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSAkk7AAsOvTw7rNLOdclqar_P8nipSY6iN87Okajo_JzZC9-Ft6j2njQ" /></div>
</a>
<br />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

http://jsfiddle.net/KumcX/1899/

```
$('p').mouseenter(function(){
    $('img').fadeIn();
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $('img').fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<ul class="hoverImg">
  <li id='img1'>text 1</li>
  <li id='img2'>text 2</li>
  <li id='img3'>text 3</li>
</ul>
<div id='selected'></div>
```

Javascript with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.hoverImg li').mouseover(function(){
    $imgLink = $(this).prop('id');
    $('#selected').html('<img src="' + $imgLink + '.gif">');
  });
})
```

View jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/3cqpd7hk/1/

Note: images are non-existent, replace with your own.

Comment: I have tried, I failed to replace the 'img' with the picture link.